# Any experience with adding Fotorama to a Sitefinity site?

Tags: sitefinity, fotorama

I am working on a project which includes a content slider (images, videos, captions) and we use Sitefinity 5.1. I've been playing with Fotorama and now want to add my content to the site. Has anyone here done that and can give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do:

1. Create a Dynamic Module with fields: Title (Short Text), Description (Long Text), Image (Media Picker). If you need other video's than the builtin Sitefinity video's, use another text field for storing the url to that video.
2. Add some content :)
3. Create or change the template that the Module Builder created for you so that the Fotorama Javascript and CSS files are loaded correctly. Make sure the markup of the generated template matches the basics of the Fotorama requirements.

Hope this helps you to get started?

Daniel.

Comment: Yes, this does. Thank you!